# Discord.py | How to remove all reactions from a message added by a specific user at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Right now my bot sends a message and reacts with a list of emojis to its own message, multiple users react using the emojis the bot reacted with. After some time the bot needs to remove all reactions except the ones the bot created.

Lets say if a bot send a message `"react text"` and reacts with emojis `"yes emoji"(reacted only by bot)` and `"no emoji"(also reacted only by bot)` and multiple users react to `"yes emoji"(then reacted by bot and multiple users)` and `"no emoji"(then also reacted by bot and multiple users)` after some time all `"yes emoji"(reacted by bot and multiple users)` and `"no emoji"(reacted by bot and multiple users)` reactions need to be removed, but bot reactions have to say, so the final result has to be bot reactions `"yes emoji"(reacted only by bot)` and `"no emoji"(also reacted only by bot)`.

I used:

`await reaction.remove(user)`

but it removes 1 reaction at a time and takes a while, can all reactions made by a specific user from a specific message be removed at once, how could that be done if possible?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Discord Bot - python clear\_reaction() clears all reactions instead of a specific one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63418818/python-discord-bot-python-clear-reaction-clears-all-reactions-instead-of-a-s)

Comment: No, in my case this method can take up to a few hours to complete because it awaits removing of each reaction individually and there are a lot of reactions, I'm searching if it's possible to remove multiple reactions made by a user or multiple users at once. Thanks for the hassle tho

Comment: Do you need these reactions to stay for a whole time? Because I think the easiest method might be to clear all the reactions using [await clear_reactions()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=reactio%20clear#discord.Message.clear_reactions) and then add them again.

Comment: Yeah, the bot reactions should stay the whole time the bot is running, clear_reactions() is not practical :\, I've looked through the docs, I guess there is no such command or fast way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `message.reactions` you get a list of reactions to that message, which you should iterate over. Then on that reaction, iterate over the users which reacted with it, and if the user is not the bot, remove the reaction for this user:

```py
for reaction in message.reactions:
    for user in await reaction.users().flatten():
        if user != client.user: #check if the user is the bot, might be slightly different for you
            await reaction.remove(user)
```

Comment: I have tried this method, but in my case this for loop can take up to a few hours to complete because this loop awaits removing of each reaction individually and there are a lot of reactions, I'm searching if it's possible to remove multiple reactions made by a user or multiple users at once. Thanks for the hassle tho

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no API call for this, meaning you'll always have to await all of them individually, if you really do not want to clear all messages.
However, that does not mean you cannot speed the previous answer up.

asyncio allows for awaiting multiple callbacks at once, and I would suggest using that functionality here:

```py
coroutines = []
for reaction in message.reactions:
    users = await reaction.users().flatten():
    if not any([user == client.user for user in users]):
         await reaction.clear()
    else:
         coroutines.extend([reaction.remove(user) for user in users])

await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)
```

Doing this might get you rate-limited, but it will probably still be faster. :-)
Also, it does still await the reaction.users() call for every reaction. If that is a problem, you can probably structure this better, but I currently don't see a good way to do this.

I hope that helps. :-)